# SML comparing files at the bit level

Tags: sml, smlnj

I am attempting to compare files in a directory using SML. Using the TextIO library is fairly easy but I need to compare the files at the bit level. That is, a binary compare. I am using a function similar to this:

```
fun listDir (s) = let
    fun loop (ds) = (case OS.FileSys.readDir (ds)
        of "" => [] before OS.FileSys.closeDir (ds)
      | file => file::loop (ds))
      val ds = OS.FileSys.openDir (s)
      in
         loop (ds) handle e => (OS.FileSys.closeDir (ds); raise (e))
      end
```

to list all the files in a given directory. But now, I need to look at the bits in each file. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the [`BinIO` structure](http://www.smlnj.org/doc/basis/pages/bin-io.html).